# Wildfly-swarm 8.5.0 creates a system property instead of a root element

Tags: wildfly-swarm

I have the following block in my yml config file:

```
access-control:
      provider: rbac
      role-mapping:
        role:
          "guest":
            include:
              user:
                "buddy"
```

When I build my project, the entries below are added to the generated standalone-full.xml

```
<system-properties>
     <property name="swarm.management.access-control.role- 
                mapping.role.guest.include.user" value="buddy"/>
      <property name="swarm.management.access-control.provider" 
                   value="rbac"/>
 </system-properties>
```

The problem is that I expected the following node to be generated:

```
<access-control provider="rbac">
   <role-mapping>
        <role name="guest">
            <include>
                <user name="buddy"/>
            </include>
        </role>
   </role-mapping>
</access-control>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to configure role-based access control *to the management interface*. This is *not* for the application itself. Is that what you really want? I wouldn't expect mgmt RBAC to be used with WildFly Swarm.

If that's what you really want, here's the JBoss EAP documentation that explains all the concepts: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html-single/how_to_configure_server_security/#role_based_access_control

To translate it to the WildFly Swarm YAML, based on http://docs.wildfly-swarm.io/2018.5.0/#_management, I believe what you need is something like this (note that I didn't try it :-) ):

```
swarm:
  management:
    security-realms:
      ManagementRealm:
        in-memory-authentication:
          users:
            albert: # creating a user in the mgmt realm
              password: einstein
    authorization-access:
      provider: rbac
      role-mappings:
        Operator: # one of the pre-defined roles, can't create new ones
          includes:
            user-albert: # by convention, should always be user-xxx or group-xxx
              name: albert
              type: user
```

But I'll repeat, I don't think you actually want this. If you could describe your usecase, I might be able to help better.

Comment: Ladicek,
  Thank you for the quick response. When I try to connect from the MDB below I get the following an error message using my original configuration:

Comment: Ladicek, I left you detailed information about the use case but for some reason someone deleted it.

Comment: I've seen your edit -- I agree with removing it, not sure why you wanted to change my answer to your question. At the same time -- you don't really need to configure `swarm.management.authorization-access`. What you're trying to do is accessing the messaging server remotely. For that, you need to configure a user in the `ApplicationRealm`. I have an example project over here that does just that: https://github.com/rhoar-qe/thorntail-test-suite/tree/master/javaee/messaging-remote

Comment: Ladicek, 
  Thank you for your help. I did not intend to change your answer rather I meant to provide a reply to it. When set up my configuration entries similarly to the ones in your example project, my MDB is able to connect to the queue and listen for messages. Is there a way to encrypt the password information stored in the yml file?

Comment: There are other options for defining users, e.g. there's an option to load users from `.properties` file. I think there's an option to load users from LDAP too, but I'm not very well versed in all the security options. In general, if you have a solution working with WildFly, it should be possible to get it working with WildFly Swarm.